# username regex in rails 4

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a user model with username attribute, everything is working fine but how to make regex on username so it accepts only alphanumeric and _ .
thanks in advance

Comment: `^\w+$` ............

Comment: Are you ending the sentence in `.` Or do you want to accept a period as well?

Comment: I want to permit the username to have a dot or underscore in between not at ending and begining

Comment: Learn the difference between Rails and Ruby before asking a question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^(\w|\.)+$
```

Which is the same as:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$
```

[Here's preview of the regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/xR1pN0/1) on regex101.com, and here's a breakdown of it

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `(` just groups the characters so a modifier can be applied
- `\w` matches any character that is **`a-z`**, **`A-Z`**, **`0-9`**, and **`_`**. Making it the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
- `|` is the OR character, making it so either the match behind or in-front of it is found.
- `\.` matches literally **`.`**.
- `)` ends the character group
- `+` makes it so the previous character group is matched once or more
- `$` matches the end of the string

If you wanted to disallow `.` and `_` in the beginning and end of the username, you could use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](\w|\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Make sure to use the `:multiline => true` option, to avoid errors.

Comment: It is throwing argument error    The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

Comment: @Mr94 This should not be a problem, as the users should not be allowed to enter multiline text in the regex, anyways.

Comment: can we prevent user from entering dot and underscore at the begining and end of the string but allow inside the string

Comment: Yes, using `^[a-zA-Z0-9](\w|\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Answer (score -1):

```
:multiline => true must be added on the username form text_field as this:

validates :username, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 20 },
                                    format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/, message: 'cannot have special characters'  },
                                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

on form: <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: " Please Enter Full Name ", autofocus: true, :multiline => true %>
```